# Making a short term/expiring app

Tags: ipad

I have searched everywhere including this site and can't find an answer. I would like to design an app for a business meeting spanning two days for a company with confidential information on it. A simple interface that allows them to see info and do a few simple things.   I would like it to expire the day after the meeting on their iPads.  (They would download it the first day of the meeting.)
I am not charging for it.  I don't need the app store.  Can I develop something on my own for them, an app with some functionality to it without all the rigamarole of being a developer? What about putting a presentation/kiosk type program on the iPad?  I would be happy with that if I could figure how they could download it(as an app?)  at the beginning of the meeting.

Thanks,
N

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use a web app?  HTML5 techniques can do quite a bit.

Comment: Also, unless you disable screenshot functionality, people will be able to make a copy of the information anyway.

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be? Your solution will depend heavily on what's at stake when a user figures out how to access the app outside of your designated time boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Apple developer account in order to deploy the app to the device.  You can use the simulator without a developer ID but you need the provisioning profile to install on a real device and the only way to get that is using your Apple account.  It's $99/year for an account, if you're doing any iOS development don't try and get around the account; just deal with it.

Do you know the people ahead of time?  If so, a system such as [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com) can be used to distribute apps as 'beta'.  But you need their email addresses in order to add them as users through TestFlight.  TestFlight does not go through the App Store.

I'm ignoring any jailbraking methods mainly because all of your users would need to be jailbroken as well.